# create PDF file in air/actionscript/flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, pdf, air

i have AIR application and I need save some data to PDF file..can i do it some simple??
is different way for save image to pdf or save only text to pdf??

thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are ActionScript 3 libraries for creating PDFs. Take a look at [purePDF](https://github.com/sephiroth74/purePDF) or [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/). Here are some of the features from purePDF:

> - support for pdf viewers display options
> - alpha transparency
> - layers and layers membership
> - support for pdf text rendering
> - tables ( nested tables, page split tables, table with images, etc...)
> - patterns, shadings patterns (linear and gradient), spot colors, rgb color
>     and cmyk color
> - linear and radial gradients with alpha
> - forms (user input forms, textfields, combo box, list, checkbox)
> - paragraphs, phrases, chunks for text manipulation
> - image patterns
> - lists
> - images ( png, tif, jpeg, bitmapdata, gif, animated gifs)
> - metadata, page header and footers
> - javascript
> - multi column text

Also take a look at some of the purepdf exampels on their [Google Code wiki](http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/wiki/Examples) or their  [examples source on GitHub](https://github.com/sephiroth74/purePDF/tree/master/examples/src).

Comment: I've heard purepdf has way more features than alive. Thats my 2 cents :)

Answer (score 3):

Check it out [alivepdf](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/)

Hopes that helps